# Is it possible to send a basic email on firebase that's not reset or change password

Tags: email, firebase

I'm just wanting to email a user a basic email like a welcome email.

Is this available on the paying plans?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nope. Firebase does not provide an open email service.

Update: But you can use Cloud Functions for Firebase to send email easily. In fact, [sending a welcome message to new users](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens) is one of the examples provided.

Comment: Which email platform would you suggest for an angular2 and firebase project? I was thinking mail chimp or send grid?

Comment: Not sure why the original question was downvoted - it's a legitimate question (although it's been asked before). The answer to the comment is that  you can obviously leverage your own mail server or work with another server service like [Zapier](http://www.zapier.com) who offers Firebase integration.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. :) With Google Cloud Function for Firebase (announced today) this is pretty trivial, several examples [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/tree/main).