# How to send data from Firebase storage to an email address?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

Currently, my app takes screen-shot after a specific time interval and store that screen-shots in the internal storage of the phone. When the phone is connected to the internet, then the screen-shots started to upload on Firebase Storage.

Firebase is storing all the data from all the users that are using my app in a single folder. I want to create a separate folder for every single user on Firebase Storage.

And want to email "folder 1" from Firebase storage to the "user 1" email address.

Note: If there any alternate way to do so, please share it with me.

Comment: I think you can't send this data via firebase console directly. Fetch the `folder1` data to your app from firebase and send this data via email.

Comment: Basically, the app is hidden from the user. Parents install this app on their child's phone in order to check out the activity of their child. So no way to fetch folder1 to child's mobile phone.

Comment: You can write a service to handle this.

Comment: that sort of stuff should be handled with a cloud function

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few steps involved in this. Stack Overflow is an ill fit for answering on such broad use-cases, but here are some steps I see:

1. [storing the files in folders](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37664385),
2. [getting a list of the files in a folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37335102),
3. [sending an email from Firebase](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34431616)